# Filtering out Orleans Reminder Grains at startup when they load into the memory from MySQL server

Tags: c#, .net, reminders, orleans

My application at the startup loads all of the reminder grains from the MySQL server but the server contains different type of reminder grains from different applications.

It means I got these kind of exceptions because in my application I do not implement these reminder grain types:

```
[2023-01-11 09:12:50,240] ERROR Silo caught an unobserved exception thrown from context [Response WorkItem Name=ResponseWorkItem:Id=47,Type=Rejection, Ctx=[LowPrioritySystemTarget: S127.0.0.1:33172:411120758*stg/Orleans.Runtime.ReminderService.LocalReminderService/00000000@S00000000]]: Grain: [LowPrioritySystemTarget: S127.0.0.1:33172:411120758*stg/Orleans.Runtime.ReminderService.LocalReminderService/00000000@S00000000] -> Unrecoverable Rejection (info:  Orleans.Runtime.OrleansException: Unexpected: Cannot find an implementation class for grain interface -1909932397
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainTypeManager.GetTypeInfo(Int32 typeCode, String& grainClass, PlacementStrategy& placement, String genericArguments) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainTypeManager/GrainTypeManager.cs:line 130
   at Orleans.Runtime.Dispatcher.AddressMessage(Message message) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Core/Dispatcher.cs:line 756
   at Orleans.Runtime.Dispatcher.AsyncSendMessage(Message message, IGrainContext sendingActivation) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Core/Dispatcher.cs:line 692) Response S127.0.0.1:33172:411120758*grn//a0b0f916-22e3-be2b-c259-5077bfeef17d->S127.0.0.1:33172:411120758*stg/Orleans.Runtime.ReminderService.LocalReminderService/00000000@S00000000 #47: Orleans.Runtime.OrleansException: Unexpected: Cannot find the directory for grain class -1909932397
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainDirectory.GrainDirectoryResolver.GetGrainDirectoryPerType(Int32 grainType) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainDirectory/GrainDirectoryResolver.cs:line 47
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainDirectory.GrainDirectoryResolver.Resolve(GrainId grainId) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainDirectory/GrainDirectoryResolver.cs:line 41
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainDirectory.GrainLocatorSelector.GetGrainLocator(GrainId grainId) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainDirectory/GrainLocatorSelector.cs:line 37
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainDirectory.GrainLocatorSelector.InvalidateCache(ActivationAddress address) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainDirectory/GrainLocatorSelector.cs:line 33
   at Orleans.Runtime.InsideRuntimeClient.ReceiveResponse(Message message) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Core/InsideRuntimeClient.cs:line 610
   at Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.ResponseWorkItem.Execute() in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Scheduler/ResponseWorkItem.cs:line 30
   at Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.TaskSchedulerUtils.RunWorkItemTask(IWorkItem todo) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Scheduler/TaskSchedulerUtils.cs:line 21
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread). eventHeuristicName=Runtime_Error_100104, Id_i=100104, IsOrleansLog_b=true Orleans.Runtime.OrleansException: Unexpected: Cannot find the directory for grain class -1909932397
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainDirectory.GrainDirectoryResolver.GetGrainDirectoryPerType(Int32 grainType) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainDirectory/GrainDirectoryResolver.cs:line 47
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainDirectory.GrainDirectoryResolver.Resolve(GrainId grainId) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainDirectory/GrainDirectoryResolver.cs:line 41
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainDirectory.GrainLocatorSelector.GetGrainLocator(GrainId grainId) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainDirectory/GrainLocatorSelector.cs:line 37
   at Orleans.Runtime.GrainDirectory.GrainLocatorSelector.InvalidateCache(ActivationAddress address) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/GrainDirectory/GrainLocatorSelector.cs:line 33
   at Orleans.Runtime.InsideRuntimeClient.ReceiveResponse(Message message) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Core/InsideRuntimeClient.cs:line 610
   at Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.ResponseWorkItem.Execute() in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Scheduler/ResponseWorkItem.cs:line 30
   at Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.TaskSchedulerUtils.RunWorkItemTask(IWorkItem todo) in /_/src/Orleans.Runtime/Scheduler/TaskSchedulerUtils.cs:line 21
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__272_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
```

Is there a possibility in the Orleans to somehow filter out these type of reminder grains which are not belonging to my application at Startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the OrleansReminderTable ServiceId was the same for my application and for others how put other type of reminders.

so I had to this:

```
 siloHostBuilder.GetBuilder()
            .Configure<ClusterOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ClusterId = "cluster-dev";
                options.ServiceId = "dev-Ac";
            });
```